# EF class context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have Microsoft VS 2010.In C# for retrieving data from database i use Ado.Net entity data model.This is Entity Framework?
I see in many articles that context created by Entity Framework is derived from dbContext but in my project context is derived form ObjectContext .
So, what is EF?

Comment: `DbContext` is used with code-first. Model-first uses `ObejctContext`

Comment: Nope. DbContext can be used with edmx files. There is a transform for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF 4.0 (which is part of the .net Framework) uses `System.Data.Entities.ObjectContext` from EF 4.3 (which was Opensourced project and is not part of the Framework) onwards uses `System.Data.Entities.DbContext`.

Both are EntityFramework. One is newer. Both uses ADO.NET under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is Entity Framework. However, context should be derived from [ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.objects.objectcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The [ObjectSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd412719%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Represents a typed entity set that is used to perform create, read,
>   update, and delete operations.
>   and it was introduced in .NET 4.0

You may also take a look on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee473442%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for additional information on object sets.